# Debugger shows "malformed expression" for a .length called on a method that returns boolean[]?

Tags: java, debugging

This isn't a code problem, more of a need for an explanation.

I have a function that is overridden and creates a boolean array, as in:

```
@Override
protected boolean[] fillSort()
{
    boolean[] vbSort = new boolean [14];
    //Do something on elements

    return vbSort;
}
```

Later on, in the base file I want to get length of that array, I invoke the overridden method and compare it, as in:

```
 if (fillSort().length == xyz.length)
```

It works correctly, however if I want to check the returned length through the debugger, it shows me that `fillSort().length` is a malformed expression and is equal to error.

If I put it on the watchlist, it returns the length of the **base** (not overridden) method. Why?

The correct length is there, the program proceeds correctly, but the debugger doesn't see it. How so?

EDIT: Using Netbeans 8.2 as IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Netbeans debugger is not clever enough to *evaluate* `fillSort()` when you hover over it.

That's why it appears to be a malformed expression.

In some way it's helping you: The fact that you are "Doing something on elements" is not relevant to the return length. Perhaps you ought not not be relying on an anonymous temporary but using something like

```
boolean[] foo = fillSort();
if (foo.length == xyz.length)
```

Comment: Is there any workaround for it, or I simply have to avoid hovering over similar methods in the future?